Scan wheel file without building it
I have some wheel file which I need to scan in Sonarqube without building it.
I tried to specify .whl extension in sonar-project.properties but sonarqube doesn't seem to know what to do with it:
sonar.python.file.suffixes=py,whl

I know workaround is to build it to some directory and then using Sonarqube.
Is there any way to do this?

Wheel files aren’t raw Python files, which is what SonarQube is able to analyze. SonarQube won’t be able to analyze precompiled binary files.
Please see more: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/scan-python-whl-file/115824
